# Need the control name

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, rad

When I am clicking an image button, I need to open a popup window in which it has a textbox, Ok and Cancel buttons. For this I thought of using RadWindow.

But I need someother control which exactly match this requirement. I don't know which control to use. Currently I am working in **Telerik** with **aspx**. I need the control name.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use `RadWindow` control

Link : http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-programming-radwindow-methods.html

Sample add controls with `ContentContainer property`

```
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
radWindow.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(textBox);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please tell me how we can place the textbox and buttons in the RadWindow from code behind. Thanks.

Comment: I'am happy to help you SO User

Comment: ContentContainer and ContentTemplate is listed. But Content is not listed. What I have to do? Thanks.

Comment: So You replace with radWindow.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(textBox);, i updated my code

Comment: Candie, You are really amazing. Thank You very much. Working Fine as expected. Great.

Answer (score -1):

What about using JavaScript in OnClientClick?

```
OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to do this?')">
```

This will return true if the user press "OK", and false if the user press Cancel.

Comment: Why would you bump and downvote a six year old answer, just because i suggested an improvement to one of your answers in a different post?